# Cucumber + Selenium Java : keep the browser open between test cases

Tags: java, selenium

I'm currently using Cucumber and Selenium WebDriver in Java to test a web application.
I'm not very happy with the fact that the browser is closed and reopened between each test cases.

First, it's pretty slow and in addition, it makes no sense to me.

What I want to do is to log off the app between each tests and keep the browser open.

I thought that this line could do the work, but it doesn't work as expected :

```
driver.navigate().to("http://myurl.url");
```

Instead of :

```
driver.get("http://myurl.url");
```

It opens a new browser. I understand why it does this, but I want to attach to my previous session of my browser.

Comment: You can use QMetry Automation Framework[ https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/qaf-2.1.9/gherkin_client.html#benefits-of-using-qaf-gherkin-scenario-factory ] and use different features of it for such web automation common requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to keep my browser open between tests.  I used the `Singleton Design Pattern` with `picocontainer`.
I declare my browser in `static` in this class.

```
public class Drivers {
    private static boolean initialized = false;
    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void initialize(){
        if (!initialized){
            initialized = true;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://myurl.url");
        }
    }
    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        return driver;
    }   
}
```

In each `StepDefinitions` class, I have a constructor that instantiates my `Singleton`.

```
public class DashboardSteps extends SuperSteps {
    Drivers context;

    @After
    public void close(Scenario scenario) {
        super.tearDown(scenario);
        loginPage = homePage.clickLogout();
        loginPage.waitPageLoaded();
    }

    public DashboardSteps(Drivers context) {
        super(context);
    }
```

The SuperSteps class :

```
public class SuperSteps {
    protected Drivers context;

    public SuperSteps(Drivers context){
        this.context = context;
    }
```

As you can see, I go back to the logIn Page after each test, so I can run every tests independently.

Comment: I see the tear in the SubStep class file. Isn't it a limitation that it has to be written in every substep class file?. Making sure the user is logged out if logged in within the initialize step solves this problem?

Comment: It's correct that you can verify that the user is logged out in the initialize. But if I remember correctly, a subClass doesn't inherit from annotations of the SuperClass, so you have to call the tearDown in each SubStep class file.

Answer (score 0):

If i m correct ur browser instantiation might be happening in a `@Before` marked `setUp` method and closing would be happening in `@After` marked `tearDown` method. If you want to stop closing of browser then just comment out that code in tearDown or whereever you are doing it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. You are correct, but the problem is that I I have to navigate to a URL. To do that, I set it in a '@Before'. In my '@After' method, I don't close the browser, but in the next test, the '@Before' open a new browser.

Comment: one more hack if you don't want to run your tests in parallel then set a flag in Before method and check in after method if the there are more tests to run or the current test is last test. As soon as you reach last test in @after close the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations. They run before the @Before and after the @After respectively. Assuming the test cases you are trying to test are in the same class, you could initialize your `WebDriver` in the `@BeforeClass` method and close it in the `@AfterClass` method.

Comment: I actually don't have all my tests in the same class. It's the reason I have this issue. I can't find a solution right now :(

Comment: One of the problems you will run into is that JUnit does not make any promises about the order of execution of your tests. You could dump them all in a Suite but that won't help the browser relaunch. Why exactly are you hoping to keep the browser open? Is it purely for speed, or are there other reasons?

Comment: The main reason is for the speed. When you are running 2k tests, the open/close add too much time in the process. But it's also because I think it doesn't need to work like that.

Comment: [This link](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/selenium-reuse-existing-browser-session-instead-of-opening-new-windows) has a few ideas that may or may not be plausible. The response by djangofan (about the second one down) mentions using Selenium Grid to run multiple tests in parallel. There are a few other options out there for running tests in parallel. But I don't know that you can actually do what you are hoping to do very cleanly. Djangofan's original solution would probably work, but as he pointed out, it wasn't really in keeping with best practices. Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: Using SpecFlow for BDD shuts down the browser between scenarios. So even tests are all in the same class the scenarios execute with clean states deliberately...